# how to pass prop server side react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using node js to render my react component...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var React = require('react');
var reactDom = require('react-dom/server');
var App = React.createFactory(require('../components/index'));

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({exists: false}));
    res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
});
module.exports = router;
```

I am trying to pass a prop, `exists: false`, to the component.

But in my actual component when I try to `console.log`...

```
render(){

    console.log(this.props.exists);
        return (
            <Register />
        );
}
```

I get `undefined` rather than `true`.

How can I fix this? Is this because the browser is re-rendering the page?

Comment: Inject props into global space inside html using template literal
` window.__initProps__=JSON.stringyfy(${props}) `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is on your client-side, React will render your `App` component one more time. This time, React will re-render which components are different from server-rendered components. It will refresh your `props.exists` to `undefined` because you don't pass anything to `App` component in your client-side code. There are some techniques to solve it. One way is that in your client-side code, you request `exists` from the server and pass it to your `App` component before rendering your application.

Comment: I see what you mean, that was helpful. But, how would I request it from the server? do you have a simple example or some sort of guidance?

Answer (score 1):

I created a very simple app based on your code and am able to see the `exists` prop set correctly in the render method. Given that this self-contained version works, I wonder if the issue lies somehow within the code of `../components/index`.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var React = require('react');
var reactDom = require('react-dom/server');
var App = React.createFactory(class extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log(this.props);
    return React.createElement('div');
  }
});

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({exists: false}));
    res.send(reactHtml);
});

var app = express();
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: So the `console.log` works server side for me, it prints the right stuff. But in the browser, when I check the console, I get undefined. Can you tell me what you get in the browser console?

Comment: In my example, it is never called in the browser because the expressjs server is only sending static markup to the client and not the React components themselves.

Comment: makes sense, do you know if its possible to send it to the react component themselves? I believe thats my problem